# <a href> link using the URL as a label

Tags: html

Is it possible to create a `hyperlink` using a variable so rather than type in text like CLICK HERE it will display the full `URL` of the page that is in the a href tag no matter what the URL is ???

```
< a href="http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpick/,">CLICK HERE< /a >
<br>Such as:<br>
< a href="http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpick/,">$0< /a ><br>
```

So http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpick/ will be on the page

Answer (score 0):

I have created a bit of javascript code that will make this happen.

```
for(var v = 0; v < document.links.length; v++)
if(document.links[v].innerHTML === "$0") document.links[v].innerHTML = document.links[v].href;
```

I hope you will be satisfied.